# Confusion between false and 0 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Basically I have the following code :

```
unset($items[array_search($i,$items)]);
```

When the key is not found the array_search returns false which is equivalent to returning 0, which results in deleting the element 0 of the array if an item value is not found.

Any Workaround for this?

Comment: use `isset()` to check whether $i is set or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$itemindex = array_search($i,$items);
if ($itemindex !== false) {
  unset($items[$itemindex]);
}
```

Using separate variable and strict comparison you will only run unset() if an item was actually found from the array. Using `!==` comparison to false you avoid confusing false with 0, since 0 is also a valid return value for array_search call, and in that case we *do* want to run unset().

Comment: @mickmackusa agreed, added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(($i = array_search($i,$items)) !== false) { 
    unset($items[$i]) 
}
```

is a possible workaround.

Comment: original function does not modify $i: it is the value to be looked for, so you shouldn't assign to it.

Comment: this overwrites `$i`, so it can impact some other logic. also, while there is one less line here than in @eis's code, it doesnt benefit, and in fact code looks less readable.

Comment: Please improve this answer with the intent to educate future readers.  Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` returns the (first) key that contains the value, or `false` if the value is not present. That means you need to check for `false` before you call `unset`, like so:

```
$ix = array_search($i,$items)
if($ix !== false) {
    unset($items[$ix]);
}
```